# template is not caught though declared correct

Tags: xslt

I've the below XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter>
<toc>
<toc-part>
<toc-div>
<toc-item>
<toc-title>2.1 Introduction</toc-title>
<toc-pg>179</toc-pg>
</toc-item>
</toc-div>
</toc-part>
</toc>

<section level="sect1">
<title><content-style font-style="bold">2.1 INTRODUCTION</content-style></title>
<section level="sect2">
<title><content-style font-style="bold">The bank</content-style></title>
<para num="2.1.1">
</para>
</section>
</section>

</chapter>
```

and below  XSLT.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"   
            xmlns:ntw="Number2Word.uri" 
            exclude-result-prefixes="ntw">
<xsl:output method="html"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>


<xsl:variable name="ThisDocument" select="document('')"/>
   <xsl:template name="toc-item" match="chapter/toc/toc-part/toc-div/toc-item">
        <xsl:variable name="tocpg">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('P',current()/toc-pg/text())"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="tocpgtag" select="translate($tocpg,'.', '-')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="chapternumber">
            <!-- Get num attribute of parent node -->
            <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::chapter[1]/@num"/>
        </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="strl">
    <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-after(@num,'.'))"/>
                </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="Brac">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="contains(substring-after(@num,'.'),'.')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="3"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="contains(@num,'(')">
                    <xsl:value-of select="2"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="1"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="NewL">
            <xsl:value-of select="string-length(substring-before(current()/toc-pg,'.'))"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="newNum">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$NewL=1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat('0',substring-before(current()/toc-pg/text(),'.'))"/>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(current()/toc-pg/text(),'.')"/>

                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>

        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="d">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('toc-item-',$ThisDocument//ntw:nums[@num=$Brac]/@word,'-level')"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="new">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('er:#LRSC_CH_',$newNum,'/',$tocpgtag)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <table class="{$d}">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="toc-item-num">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()/@num"/>
            </td>
            <td class="toc-title">
            <xsl:value-of select="current()/toc-title"/>
            </td>

            <td class="toc-pg">
            <xsl:variable name="refe">
            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="//section/title/content-style[upper-case(./text())=upper-case(current()/toc-title/text())]/section[1]/para[1]/@num[1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="//section/title/content-style[upper-case(./text())=upper-case(current()/toc-title/text())]/section[1]/para[1]/@num[1]"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="//section/title/content-style[upper-case(text())=upper-case(current()/toc-title/text())]/para[1]/@num[1]"/>            
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:variable name="full">
                  <xsl:value-of select="$refe"/>
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:variable name="pre">
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before($refe,'.')"/>              
              </xsl:variable>
              <xsl:variable name="post">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($refe,'.')"/></xsl:variable>
              <xsl:variable name="siz">
                  <xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="$pre>'1'">
<xsl:value-of select="concat('LRSC_CH_',$pre,'/P',translate($full,'.','-'))"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="concat('LRSC_CH_0',$pre,'/P',translate($full,'.','-'))"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:otherwise>                  
                  </xsl:choose>
              </xsl:variable>
              <a href="{$siz}">
                  <xsl:value-of select="./toc-pg"/>
              </a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <xsl:if test="./toc-subitem">
        <xsl:for-each select="./toc-subitem">
<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>       
 </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:if>
        <!--</table>-->
    </xsl:template>
   <ntw:nums num="1" word="first"/>
<ntw:nums num="2" word="second"/>
<ntw:nums num="3" word="third"/>
<ntw:nums num="4" word="forth"/>
<ntw:nums num="5" word="fifth"/>
<ntw:nums num="6" word="sixth"/>
<ntw:nums num="7" word="seventh"/>
<ntw:nums num="8" word="eighth"/>
<ntw:nums num="9" word="nighth"/>
<ntw:nums num="10" word="tenth"/>
</xsl:style-sheet>
```

here i've declared `<xsl:when test="//section/title/content-style[upper-case(./text())=upper-case(current()/toc-title/text())]/section[1]/para[1]/@num[1]">` to get the following page num of section tag, but here it is not getting caught properly, when i make it

```
<xsl:when test="//section[upper-case(title/content-style/text())=upper-case(current()/toc-title/text())]/section[1]/para[1]/@num[1]">
```

it is throwing me an error as below.

```
XPTY0004: The supplied sequence ('3' item(s)) has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:string ('zero or one')
```

please let me know where am i going wrong and how to catch the sequence.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of XSLT are you using? Also, where have you declared $ThisDocument?

Comment: Hi @LingamurthyCS, i use XSLT2.0 and I've updated my question

Answer (score 1):

This is your current expression...

```
<xsl:when test="//section/title/content-style[upper-case(./text())
                = upper-case(current()/toc-title/text())]/section[1]/para[1]/@num[1]">
```

If you remove the conditional check on the **toc-title** it becomes this

```
<xsl:when test="//section/title/content-style/section[1]/para[1]/@num[1]">
```

This should (hopefully) highlight your problem as it is looking for a **section** element under the **content-style** object. Looking at your XML, this is not the case.

As your **section** element is under another **section** element, you possible need to nest your conditions here. Try this instead

```
<xsl:when test="//section[title/content-style[upper-case(text())
                = upper-case(current()/toc-title/text())]]/section[1]/para[1]/@num">
```

There is maybe a case for using a variable here, to improve readability:

```
<xsl:variable name="toc-title" select="upper-case(current()/toc-title/text())" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="//section[title/content-style[upper-case(text()) = $toc-title]]/section[1]/para[1]/@num">
```

Having said that, I couldn't recreate the error when I used your alternate expression.